# Django : mysql : 1045, "Access denied for user

Tags: mysql, django, mysql-error-1045

I have the whole setup working for months on my local computer.
I'm installing on a remote site now.
Created a fresh mysql DB, and created a new user ("someuser") and gave it complete grants, like so -

> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'someuser'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'somepassword' WITH GRANT OPTION;

I have sync'd the db, using "python manage.py syncdb" and the correct tables were created.
My settings.py has this same user.

But when I try to login a user through the application, and it hits the DB, I see the following in the logs -

> (1045, "Access denied for user 'someuser'@'localhost' (using password: YES)")

I logged in through mysql (installed on the same box as django) and checked the grants and it correctly shows -

> Grants for someuser@localhost
>   GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON * . * TO 'someuser'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*thesaltedpasswordOverHere' WITH GRANT OPTION

I don't want to use the root user/password for django, since it doesn't seem the correct way.

Any pointers as to what might be wrong ?

Comment: Do you remember if you got this working?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I do it like this for a database named foo_db:

```
create database foo_db;
create user foo_user identified by 'foo_password';
grant all on foo_db.* to 'foo_user'@'%';
flush privileges;
```

Comment: Thanks that helped ! I think the reason is that I created the users first and then the database. That is very odd, 'coz when you look at the grant & it says you have access to *.* it is misleading. It should apply to whatever is created after that instance as well.

Comment: I am actually trying to do the same thing PlanetUnknown did.  I followed your method but I still get the same error.

Comment: `grant all` is very broad and might impose a security thread. It may *work* but is unsafe and risky. Maybe consider switching to to more distinct privileges?

Comment: Here I had granted access to `localhost` but in my `DATABASE_URL` the IP address `127.0.0.1` was written which is **not** the same (security).

Answer (score 11):

In my case the settings.py has the following:

```
    DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'TRYDJANGO',
        'USERNAME':'user_trydjango',
        'PASSWORD':'passtry',
        'PORT':'3306',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
    }
}
```

And it works if I change the 'USERNAME' to 'USER':

```
    DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'TRYDJANGO',
        'USER':'user_trydjango',
        'PASSWORD':'passtry',
        'PORT':'3306',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

as far as i understood someuser  is a DB guest user and not the admin one, right?

If so, from your MySQL DB admin user, grant someuser to access MySQL environment table 'mysql.user' as follow:

GRANT SELECT ON `mysql`.`user` TO 'someuser'@'%';

To me it worked,
Ivan

Answer (score 1):

Refering to the answer of @duffymo and changed the last statement could work for me.

```
create database foo_db;
create user foo_user identified by 'foo_password';
grant all on foo_db.* to foo_user@localhost identified by 'foo_password' with grant option;
```

Answer (score 1):

My error message indicated that there wasn't password supplied to the database:

> django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1045, "Access denied for user 'mylocalusername'@'localhost' (using password: NO)")

The `manage.py` should pick up the database access credentials from the `settings.py`, that's a specific database user (and of course that user's password as well). It's a security mistake to react to my error message by granting database login privileges to the local user.

In my case there were problems with the `settings.py` (we were restructuring our build pipeline from django pipeline to webpack) and I needed to remove pipeline related parts from my `settings.py` for the fix. It's a question why I didn't get any python error message about the `settings.py` problems, but instead I got this error which is not local to the real problem. That error message is just a transitive result of the source problem. Once I fixed the `manage.py`, the credentials were picked up from the DATABASE settings as usual and everything went smooth.

---

In our case we were using `django-pipeline` before webpack (more specifically `pip` packages `django-pipeline-browserify==0.4.1` and
`django-pipeline==1.6.8`), so once we transitioned I had to just remove these lines from settings:

```
NODE_MODULES_BIN = '/home/myuser/sourcerepositorydir/node_modules/.bin/'
PIPELINE['SASS_BINARY'] = '/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/sass-3.5.3/bin/sass'
PIPELINE['BABEL_BINARY'] = '{}{}'.format(NODE_MODULES_BIN, 'babel')
PIPELINE['BROWSERIFY_BINARY'] = '{}{}'.format(NODE_MODULES_BIN, 'browserify')
PIPELINE_BROWSERIFY_BINARY = PIPELINE['BROWSERIFY_BINARY']
PIPELINE['BROWSERIFY_ENV'] = {'NODE_ENV': 'development'}
PIPELINE['BROWSERIFY_ARGUMENTS'] = PIPELINE['BROWSERIFY_ARGUMENTS'] + ' --debug'
```

Until that I was just getting nonsensical error messages.

Comment: Please let us know what exact changes made to settings.py to make it work. we are facing the same issue

Comment: @Shiva I added the details

Answer (score 0):

@ mattblang:

In this case it helps if the host is set in the actually used `settings.py` file too.

For me it is `/etc/graphite/local_settings.py` where the `DATABASES Stanzas` had a wrong value, for HOST there was:
`'HOST': '127.0.0.1',`

Because during the runtime of syncdb command it searched for localhost, I changed it to
`'HOST': 'localhost',`

Now it looks something like this:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'NAME': 'graphite',
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'USER': 'graphite',
        'PASSWORD': 'thepasswordyouchoose',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '3306'
    }
}
```

... and now the `syncdb` command `python manage.py syncdb` runs successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Also change the port number to '3307'if MySQl-python 64-bit in settings.py, Then only the connection happening in Windows and MySql 5.7 django.

'3306' for MySQl-python 32-bit

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'NAME': 'graphite',
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'USER': 'graphite',
        'PASSWORD': 'thepasswordyouchoose',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '3307'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this config and it works.

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'read_default_file': '/etc/my.cnf',
        },
        #'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that all I have done is:

1. drop my database
2. drop the user
3. re-create the user
4. re-create the database
5. grant to this user, flush privileges

and then it begin to work.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to contribute an answer. It’s because of helpful peers like yourself that we’re able to learn together as a community. Here are a few tips on how to make your answer great: [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I got the following error:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'MySQLdb'
>   django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb
>   module. Did you install mysqlclient?

**Solution # 01:**
Verify that If you user has permission to access the database and perform the DDL & DML operations on it.

**Solution # 02:**
Changed the database configuration in ***settings.py*** file

**From:**

```
DATABASES = {

'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'db_name',
        'USER': 'root'
    }
}
```

**To:**

```
DATABASES = {

'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'db_name',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': 'root',
        'HOST': 'localhost',   # Or an IP Address that your DB is hosted on
        'PORT': '3306',
    }
}
```

**And** it started working.

Answer (score 0):

i solve my problem in cpanel/mysql add user to database i hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue while trying to connect to a remote DB after migrating it from my local host. I was able to clear this issue by deleting all the prior migrations, then running

```
python manage.py makemigrations
```

after that,

```
python manage.py migrate
```

solved my issue so I hope this helps.