# Using MySQL with Django - Access denied for user '@'localhost

Tags: python, mysql, django

So I'm learning Django (1, 3, 1, 'final', 0) through this resource: http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter05/

I installed 'mysql-server' and 'python-mysqldb' via Synaptic. I changed the relevant setting in settings.py.

The book mentioned above tells us to run from the manage.py shell:

```
>>> from django.db import connection
>>> cursor = connection.cursor()
```

I get this error after running these commands:

```
OperationalError: (1044, "Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'mydb'")

  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/__init__.py", line 250, in cursor
    cursor = self.make_debug_cursor(self._cursor())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 322, in _cursor
    self.connection = Database.connect(**kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 81, in Connect
    return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 187, in __init__
    super(Connection, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
OperationalError: (1044, "Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'mydb'")
```

MySQL did ask me to set a root password when I installed it the first time, would that be utilized here? or is it something else?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Your user does not have an access to database. Use the commands below to set up your database.

```
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS `mydb`;
CREATE DATABASE `mydb`
    DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8
    DEFAULT COLLATE utf8_general_ci;

USE 'mysql';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON mydb.* TO 'mydb_user'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'your_password'

WITH GRANT OPTION;
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Also, you need to have enough privileges to run it. Save it as script.sql then,

```
$mysql -u root -p < script.sql
```

Than on to settings.py where you need to make sure your db settings are set up properly

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'mydb',                  
        'USER': 'mydb_user',             
        'PASSWORD': 'your_password',                  
        'HOST': '',                     
        'PORT': '',                      
    }
}
```

and

```
python manage.py syncdb
```

and you're done.

Comment: I get the same error if I try "DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS `mydb`;"


ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'mydb'

Comment: Check TEST=True in settings

Answer (score 4):

I also ran into this problem while following the Django tutorial on testing (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial05/).  When trying to test the polls app, I received the following error:

```
user@host:~/django/mysite$ python manage.py test polls

Creating test database for alias 'default'...
Got an error creating the test database: (1044, "Access denied for user 'admin'@'localhost' to database 'test_django_mysite'")
Type 'yes' if you would like to try deleting the test database 'test_django_mysite', or 'no' to cancel:
```

The problem is that django is creating a temporary database called test_django_mysite.
I was able to solve this problem by granting access to 'admin'@'localhost' on the test_django_mysite database that it was trying to create.

```
mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON test_django_mysite.* TO admin@localhost IDENTIFIED BY 'mypassword';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.04 sec)
```

It's worth noting that I only granted the privileges to test_django_mysite.  I didn't need to actually create it.

Comment: yet another reason why MySQL sucks!  With postgres, I was able to do $ psql > alter role 'username' with create;  AND THAT's IT.  I spent 30 minutes on this today, and this is the only answer that worked!

Answer (score 0):

The django book is fairly old by now. in particular, database settings are now a dictionary, rather then the bunch of variables described in the django book.

looking at the last line of your traceback, it looks like it's trying connect without a username.

try changing

```
DATABASE_ENGINE = ''
DATABASE_NAME = ''
DATABASE_USER = ''
DATABASE_PASSWORD = ''
```

to

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': '',
        'NAME': ''
        'USER': ''
        # etc
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm using Django (1, 3, 1, 'final', 0)


I wasn't aware that DjangoBook is outdated. It's been a very good tool to help me learn till now, do you recommend I leave it?

Actually my django setting does look like a dictionary, so that isn't the issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you changed the database password and updated settings.py, you will also have to restart the wsgi.py process, for example by restarting apache.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that I was editing **settings.py** whereas configuration should have been done in **local_settings.py**

Now everything seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and yet all settings seemed correct. I later noticed MySQL was using port 3308 and yet I had port 3306 in my Django settings file. I updated the settings file to resolve the issue.

Answer (score -1):

Just gonna leave my answer here because I lost few good minutes (almost hour) on this matter.

Watch Your copy-paste :) Unfortunately, mysql return success while granting priviliges for not existing user to not existing database...

Both queries:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON python_user.* TO 'python_db'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

and:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON python_db.* TO 'python_user'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION
```

will return success. Aldo I don't have such a user called python_db and db named python_user. :) That's sad. My mistake but also MySql was not helpful enough with output. :)

Answer (score -1):

You need to verify database configurations in *settings.py* file and also if your db user has privilege to access the database and perform operations on it.

Please see if solutions mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52700000/1846656) works for you.