# c# mysql select with where condition

Tags: c#, mysql

WHERE  status=  'โกดัง' "     I try this it does not work ( it is utf8 (Thai language) Do I need to set up something in C# to make it know is utf8 or be cause of I can not use 'โกดัง'

I use c# and mysql  the code is work until I fill WHERE status= 'โกดัง' before String cmdText = "SELECT * FROM trackingbymail "; it work

```
String str = @"server=localhost;database=asianimport;userid=tga;password=se57ui849;";


String cmdText = "SELECT * FROM trackingbymail WHERE  status=  'โกดัง' ";
                MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(cmdText, con);
                MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

Comment: "it does not work" Would you mind being a little more descriptive?

Comment: Check collation and character set of your db
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11170133/using-mysql-with-django-access-denied-for-user-localhost/11170252#11170252

Comment: the code is work until I fill WHERE  status=  'โกดัง'  before String cmdText = "SELECT * FROM trackingbymail  "; it work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Ensure that the collation of your database of table is a UTF-8 collation (i.e. `utf8_general_ci` or one of its relations)
2. Add `Charset=utf8;` to your connection string.

"Server=localhost;Database=test;Uid=test;Pwd=test;Charset=utf8;"

Source: [MySQL C# Text Encoding Problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/942277/mysql-c-sharp-text-encoding-problems)

Anyway if it can't solve, you can store the bytes instead the string. But probably it isn't the best way to solve that...

```
UTF8Encoding utf8 = new UTF8Encoding();
string unicodeString = "โกดัง";
byte[] encodedBytes = utf8.GetBytes(unicodeString);
```

then when you need you could back to string:

```
Encoding.UTF8.GetString(encodedBytes);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should save your source code file as UTF-8.

Have you tried this?