# django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1045, u"Access denied for user 'my_user'@'localhost' (using password: NO)")

Tags: mysql, django, django-mysql

I am trying to connect to MySQL from DJango. 
My settings.py file:

```
DATABASES = {
          'default':{
             'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
             'Name': 'my_db',
             'User': 'my_user',
             'Password': 'my_pass',
             'Host': 'localhost',
             'Port': '3306'
          }
}
```

}

I am getting following error.

**django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1045, u"Access denied for user 'my_user'@'localhost' (using password: NO)")**

I have tried following steps to solve the problem.

I have created the user:

```
    create user 'my_user'@'localhost' identified by 'my_pass';
```

And granted access as follows:

```
    grant all on *.* to 'my_user'@'localhost';
    flush privileges;
```

But, even though my problem not yet fixed.
Can someone help me?

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe duplicated of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11170133/using-mysql-with-django-access-denied-for-user-localhost/11170252

Comment: I have posted the question after trying out the solution. I have granted the access to the user. But, even though I am getting the same error.

Comment: @ShankarMuthusamy Are you able to access mysql shell using above credentials using mysql client?

Comment: @RiteshAgrawal, yes I could able to access mysql shell using the credentials.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting Django up to use MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19189813/setting-django-up-to-use-mysql)

Answer (score 0):

All the database config variables need to be caps but you have provided in title case.

```
DATABASES = {
      'default':{
         'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
         'NAME': 'my_db',
         'USER': 'my_user',
         'PASSWORD': 'my_pass',
         'HOST': 'localhost',
         'PORT': '3306'
      }
}
```