# Django Settings not picking up user

Tags: mysql, django

I'm working on my first Django project and struggling to connect it to my MySQL database. My project is struggling to pick up database values from settings. Here is my issue.

settings.py:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'django',
        'USER': 'admin',
    }
}
```

I have removed the password, host, and port for now as I'm trying to isolate the issue with user.

I run `python manage.py diffsettings` and the result includes, clearly containing the user:

```
DATABASES = {'default': {'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql', 'NAME': 'django', 'USER': 'admin', 'ATOMIC_REQUESTS': False, 'AUTOCOMMIT': True, 'CONN_MAX_AGE': 0, 'OPTIONS': {}, 'TIME_ZONE': None, 'PASSWORD': '', 'HOST': '', 'PORT': '', 'TEST': {'CHARSET': None, 'COLLATION': None, 'NAME': None, 'MIRROR': None}}}
```

However, when I run `python manage.py migrate`, I get the following error:

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1044, "Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'django'")
```

You can see here that the user is missing. It's showing `''@'localhost'` instead of `'admin'@'localhost'` The strange part is that the database name is being picked up, but the user isn't.

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Did you try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11170252/9733868)?

Comment: I know my user has access to the database. I can login to it through MySQL Workbench and run any operation. My issue is that django does not seem to be picking up the username from settings. I also get an unknown command error when I try to use syncdb

Answer (score 0):

I'm on the path to solving this. Originally, I was trying to configure the settings through an options read_default_file cnf and I only moved the user into settings.py in an attempt to debug this.

If I place all of my configuration in settings, then django connects to mysql properly. Now I just need to figure out how to get the cnf file working.