# Django MySQL OperationalError: 1044

Tags: mysql, django, django-apps

I am trying to add the a app called 'login'. I was told by the documentation tutorial to use the command:

```
    python manage.py sql login
```

However, I get the error:

```
    OperationalError: (1044, "Access denied for user 'classdummy'@'localhost' to database 'classydummy'")
```

I logged into root on MySQL and used the command:

```
    grant all privileges on classdummy.* to 'classdummy'@'localhost'
```

in order to grant all privileges. However, when I run the same python command, I get the same error!

Any help appreciated! thank you!

Comment: Have a look at:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2443419/django-mysql-1045-access-denied-for-user

Comment: I did that and I get the same error...