# django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1045, Access denied for user '<user>'@'localhost'

Tags: python, django, mariadb, access-denied

I can't get my Django project to load my database correctly. It throws this error.

I'm running MariaDB with Django, and I uninstalled all MySQL

I added the user by running:

```
create database foo_db;
create user foo_user identified by 'foo_password';
grant all on foo_db.* to 'foo_user'@'%';
flush privileges;
```

as suggested by [this post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2443419/django-mysql-1045-access-denied-for-user)

The console is throwing me this error back when I try to run `./manage.py runserver`

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1045, "Access denied for user '<user>'@'localhost' (using password: YES)")
```

I have run the 'create user' command and created the user to match my setup script, which has the default set as:

```
        'ENGINE': 'django.contrib.gis.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'company_production',
        'USER': 'companydev',
        'PASSWORD': 'companydevpass',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '',
        'ATOMIC_REQUESTS': True
```

I have tried everything I've been able to find on here related to the error its thrown, but nothing has been working.

I'm running Mac OSX 10.11.1 El Capitan and MariaDB version 10.1.8 if that's relevant at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I use to re-create MySQL databases for Django projects:

```
tmp="/tmp/mysql-tools.sh.tmp"

setup-db ( ) {
    cat <<EOF > $tmp
DROP DATABASE $DB;
CREATE DATABASE $DB;
GRANT USAGE on *.* to '${DB_USER}'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '${DB_PASS}';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ${DB}.* to '${DB_USER}'@'localhost';
EOF
    cat $tmp
    mysql -f -u ${MYSQL_ROOTUSR} -p${MYSQL_ROOTPWD} < $tmp
    rm $tmp
}
```

**Warning**: this drops and re-creates!

Where:

- DB: the database name
- DB_USER: the django database user
- DB_PASS: the password for the mysql connection for the Django database user
- MYSQL_ROOTUSR: the mysql root user (must have permissions to create databases)
- MYSQL_ROOTPWD: the mysql root password

Export those in your environment

Comment: I know this is a delayed reply, but thanks for this! Running this script fixed my issue! Or at least, got me past that error and opened up another one for me! haha thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Your Error gives you a clue where you're going wrong...

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1045, "Access denied for user '<user>'@'localhost' (using password: YES)")
```

That means `django` trying to access the database with user `user`, not what you have defined in `settings.py`.

I guess you have forgotten to do a `python manage.py migrate` before doing `runserver`, as your settings are not yet reflected inside `django` engine.

Answer (score 1):

It may due to Django tried to use the wrong user instead of what you set up in MySQL DB

change setting from USERNAME -> USER could help:)

I got the error with

'NAME': 'database name',
        'USERNAME':'root',
        'PASSWORD':'******',
        'PORT':'3306',
        'HOST': 'localhost',

But it worked with ---

'NAME': 'database name',
        'USER':'root',
        'PASSWORD':'********',
        'PORT':'3306',
        'HOST': 'localhost',