# solution for django.db.utils.OperationalError

Tags: python, django, database

I am a student (using `Ubuntu`) who has recently started with studying `database` and `django`.

I have been trying to open one of my team member's `django web`, but when I type

```
python manage.py runserver
```

it shows me a message at the end saying

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1698, "Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'")
```

Is there any good solution for this problem? 
I have been searching for similar problems, but still haven't found
a good solution yet. Please let me know if there is any other additional
information needed. Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39281594/error-1698-28000-access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost/47238738

Answer (score 2):

Have you setup properly the `config` file? If yes, please check user privilege for the assigned db.

Here is the one way you can create db and user and grant the permission.

```
CREATE DATABASE test_db;
CREATE USER test_user identified by 'test_password';
GRANT ALL on test_db.* to 'test_user'@'%';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Many developer experience the same issue. Please check the other thread which many have explained in details the same issue.

[Using MySQL with Django - Access denied for user '@'localhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11170133/using-mysql-with-django-access-denied-for-user-localhost?noredirect=1&lq=1)

[django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1045, Access denied for user '<user>'@'localhost'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33750895/django-db-utils-operationalerror-1045-access-denied-for-user-userlocalh?noredirect=1&lq=1)