# Django unable to access database/Access denied for user@localhost

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-settings, django-manage.py

I'm currently having some trouble running a Django app, Scalica. It was working just fine last night, I must have done something wrong to break it--I'm just not sure what it is.

When I try to run the following:

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-28-29:~/largescale/scalica/web/scalica$ python manage.py migrate
```

I receive this error message:

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1045, "Access denied for user 'appserver'@'localhost' (using password: YES)")
```

The thing is, I don't believe that this app should even know about the user appserver. The manage.py file in which I'm trying to execute, has settings.DATABASES set like so:

```
# Database
DATABASES = {
  'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
    'OPTIONS': {
      'read_default_file': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '..', '..', 'db', 'my.cnf'),
    },
  }
}
```

I'm running Scalica remotely, and save the data on the remote server to display it onto a webpage. This is then scraped by a scraper that's running locally THEN it gets saved onto a database under appserver user. So appserver should not be accessing Scalica database at all. I think that manage.py is calling a wrong settings.py. How do I fix it if that is the case? And if my guess is wrong, if anyone can offer some advise, that would be helpful.

Below is the content of manage.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import sys

if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "scalica.settings")

    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line

    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

**EDIT**

I have already tried dropping existing user appserver and recreating it, giving it permissions to the database metrix1 and metrix2, which are utilized by the local app. However, that didn't solve my problem. I'm having trouble with a Scalica app running remotely that **should have nothing to do with appserver.**

Below is the user privileges for appserver:

```
| 'appserver'@'localhost'        | def           | SELECT                  | NO           |
| 'appserver'@'localhost'        | def           | INSERT                  | NO           |
| 'appserver'@'localhost'        | def           | UPDATE                  | NO           |
| 'appserver'@'localhost'        | def           | DELETE                  | NO           |
| 'appserver'@'localhost'        | def           | CREATE                  | NO           |
| 'appserver'@'localhost'        | def           | DROP                    | NO           |
| 'appserver'@'localhost'        | def           | RELOAD                  | NO           |
| 'appserver'@'localhost'        | def           | SHUTDOWN                | NO           |
| 'appserver'@'localhost'        | def           | PROCESS                 | NO           |
| 'appserver'@'localhost'        | def           | FILE                    | NO           |
| 'appserver'@'localhost'        | def           | REFERENCES              | NO           |
| 'appserver'@'localhost'        | def           | INDEX                   | NO           |
| 'appserver'@'localhost'        | def           | ALTER                   | NO           |
| 'appserver'@'localhost'        | def           | SHOW DATABASES          | NO           |
| 'appserver'@'localhost'        | def           | SUPER                   | NO           |
| 'appserver'@'localhost'        | def           | CREATE TEMPORARY TABLES | NO           |
| 'appserver'@'localhost'        | def           | LOCK TABLES             | NO           |
| 'appserver'@'localhost'        | def           | EXECUTE                 | NO           |
| 'appserver'@'localhost'        | def           | REPLICATION SLAVE       | NO           |
| 'appserver'@'localhost'        | def           | REPLICATION CLIENT      | NO           |
| 'appserver'@'localhost'        | def           | CREATE VIEW             | NO           |
| 'appserver'@'localhost'        | def           | SHOW VIEW               | NO           |
| 'appserver'@'localhost'        | def           | CREATE ROUTINE          | NO           |
| 'appserver'@'localhost'        | def           | ALTER ROUTINE           | NO           |
| 'appserver'@'localhost'        | def           | CREATE USER             | NO           |
| 'appserver'@'localhost'        | def           | EVENT                   | NO           |
| 'appserver'@'localhost'        | def           | TRIGGER                 | NO           |
| 'appserver'@'localhost'        | def           | CREATE TABLESPACE       | NO           |
+--------------------------------+---------------+-------------------------+--------------+
```

Comment: it'seems like you have ssh access problem, try to remove the remote host from **.ssh/known_hosts/** file and ssh the server again.

Comment: @DhiaTN Hi, thank you for your comment. I deleted the remote host from my local .ssh/known_hosts/ file and tried to ssh the server again. Unfortunately, that didn't solve the issue. I'm still receiving: django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1045, "Access denied for user 'appserver'@'localhost' (using password: YES)")

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django : mysql : 1045, "Access denied for user](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2443419/django-mysql-1045-access-denied-for-user)

Comment: @DhiaTN I've already tried the above, with no luck. :( Why did you think it was an ssh access problem?

Comment: since it's remote connection, first though was ssh problem.

Comment: try to connect to your database from the shell without running the project and check if it's working?? if it's not try to ssh to the server and connect to your DB from the shell locally. So we can identify if the problem is in the database or in the project.

Comment: @DhiaTN Hi, what do you mean by that? you mean open mysql shell as appserver and access scalica database